# 401 response during OAuth authorization in flickr

Tags: android, oauth, flickr, flickrj

I develop android application that backup photos to flickr.

I had the next problem several times: 
Sometimes I receive 401 response ("Response Code: 401, Response Message: Unauthorized, Error: oauth_problem=token_rejected") instead of response with access token, during Exchanging the Request Token for an Access Token.

This problems happens mostly when I have bad internet connection (when I am suing 3g internet).

Here are logs that shows this behavior:

```
2015-01-07 17:12:00,603 DEBUG [oauth.OAuthInterface]-[122] Getting Request Token with parameters: www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token [
Parameter [name=oauth_callback, value={MY_APP_NAME}-flickr://callback], 
Parameter [name=oauth_consumer_key, value={MY_CONSUMER_KEY}], 
Parameter [name=oauth_nonce, value=154099562370628], 
Parameter [name=oauth_signature_method, value=HMAC-SHA1], 
Parameter [name=oauth_timestamp, value=1420630920], 
Parameter [name=oauth_version, value=1.0], 
Parameter [name=oauth_signature, value=oVkmG/7nOoiO0P6Dm2j4Aql4lDs=]
] 

2015-01-07 17:12:01,695 DEBUG [oauth.OAuthInterface]-[136] 
Response: {oauth_token_secret={RESULT_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET}, oauth_callback_confirmed=true, oauth_token={RESULT_OAUTH_TOKEN}}
```

After that I open next url in browser for user:
url = m.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={RESULT_OAUTH_TOKEN}&perms=write

After authorization I get next callback:

```
{MY_APP_NAME}-flickr://callback?oauth_token={RESULT_OAUTH_TOKEN}&oauth_verifier=59bbeb1cb3ffedca
```

Using verifier I make next request:

```
2015-01-07 17:12:47,043 DEBUG [flickrjandroid.REST]-[288] Send Post Input parameters [
Parameter [name=oauth_consumer_key, value={MY_CONSUMER_KEY}], 
Parameter [name=oauth_nonce, value=154146242657849], 
Parameter [name=oauth_signature_method, value=HMAC-SHA1], 
Parameter [name=oauth_timestamp, value=1420630967], 
Parameter [name=oauth_token, value={RESULT_OAUTH_TOKEN}], 
Parameter [name=oauth_verifier, value=59bbeb1cb3ffedca], 
Parameter [name=oauth_version, value=1.0], 
Parameter [name=oauth_signature, value=yZjgD6iKGxn4lzJVuZHnEaqWsHE=]] api.flickr.com:443/services/oauth/access_token
```

The response is:

Response Code: 401, Response Message: Unauthorized, Error: oauth_problem=token_rejected

What can cause the reject of token? 
Can I try make another request using same verifier after getting 401 response or this will also return 401 response?

This problem happens just sometimes, usually during bad internet connection. 
For authorization I use flickrj-android-2.1.1

Comment: Hi Rostyslav Roshak did you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

These are some causes that can reject the token:

- Request token has been already used to exchange for an access token.
- Request token doesn't match the Consumer Key.
- Verification code received from the Consumer isn't valid.